# How to join a calculated column from a table to collection

Tags: customer, collection, sql, grid, join

I have a table name `stat_customer` look like this:

[image: stat_customer table]

I want to add a column `page_view` to customer collection to show at grid page. `page_view` is total page view of product page for each customer. My SQL query looks like:

> SELECT sum(`page_view`) as page_view, customer_id FROM `stat_customer`
>   WHERE `page_type` = 'product' GROUP BY `customer_id`;

But I don't know how to join it with customer collection. Can anyone help me please ?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying this way:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
      $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect("page_view", "sum({{page_view}})", "page_view");
      $collection->groupByAttribute("page_view");
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

But getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in
>   E:\XAMPP\htdocs\stat\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php
>   on line 513

Comment: are you want to add this stat_customer table to Admin >Customer Grid..

Comment: Yes, I want to add 1 column `page_view` calculated by my query to customer grid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the methods `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract::addExpressionFieldToSelect()` for standard models:

```
/**
 * Add attribute expression (SUM, COUNT, etc)
 * Example: ('sub_total', 'SUM({{attribute}})', 'revenue')
 * Example: ('sub_total', 'SUM({{revenue}})', 'revenue')
 * For some functions like SUM use groupByAttribute.
 *
 * @param string $alias
 * @param string $expression
 * @param array $fields
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function addExpressionFieldToSelect($alias, $expression, $fields)
```

And `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::addExpressionAttributeToSelect()` for EAV models:

```
/**
 * Add attribute expression (SUM, COUNT, etc)
 *
 * Example: ('sub_total', 'SUM({{attribute}})', 'revenue')
 * Example: ('sub_total', 'SUM({{revenue}})', 'revenue')
 *
 * For some functions like SUM use groupByAttribute.
 *
 * @param string $alias
 * @param string $expression
 * @param string $attribute
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function addExpressionAttributeToSelect($alias, $expression, $attribute)
```

### Usage

```
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect("page_view", "sum({{page_view}})", ["page_view"]);
//                                      ^ alias      ^ expression          ^ used fields

$collection->getSelect()->group("main_table.entity_id");
```

or

```
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect("page_view", "sum({{page_view}})", "page_view");
//                                          ^ alias      ^ expression          ^ used attribute

$collection->getSelect()->group("main_table.entity_id");
```

Note that the method suggested in the doc block, `groupByAttribute()` is only used to group by EAV attributes, not static columns like the entity id.

Comment: Good answer.. I just typing answer.. But you give first +V1

Comment: Not sure why I got this error: Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection::addExpressionFieldToSelect(). My collection is: $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection'). I'm using magento 1.6.1.0

Comment: OK for EAV collections like the customer collection it works a bit different. See updated answer

Comment: I've tried to use the second way but got this error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\stat\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php on line 513.

Comment: it cannot be the same error with the method name `addExpressionAttributeToSelect`

Comment: I've just updated my code to my question. Could you take a look please ?. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. Of course you don't want to group by `page_view`, but to group by the customer id `$collection->getSelect()->group("main_table.entity_id")`

Comment: I've tried but still got same error. It seems that problem was in this line: $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect("page_view", "sum({{page_view}})", "page_view");

Comment: OK, I think I understand the problem: `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` only works with expressions based on actual EAV attributes, not joined tables, while `addExpressionFieldToSelect` is not available. You should use `joinTable` and specify the expression as `Zend_Db_Expr`. I will update the answer later with more information when I find the time

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm looking for your answer. Nice explanation!

Answer (score 3):

I've found my answered by using the following join:

```
$statTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('stat_customer');
    $collection->getSelect()
      ->join(array("stat" => $statTable), "e.entity_id = stat.customer_id", array("*","sum(stat.page_view) as page_view" ))
      ->where('stat.page_type = "product"')
      ->group('e.entity_id');
```

It works great.

Answer (score 2):

**First,**

Need  to add this table magento  to  Customer collection on  `prepareCollection()`  at class  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid`

```
$subSelect =  Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getConnection( 'core_read' )->select()
                 ->from(array('o' =>'stat_customer'), 'SUM(o.page_view)')
                 ->where('o.customer_id = e.entity_id ')
        $subSelect->where('o.page_type = ?', 'product') ;

$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('page_view_count' => $subSelect))->group("o.customer_id");
```

**Second,**

You need to this column on grid using `addColumn` function `_prepareColumns()` **(class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid )**

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    $this->addColumn('page_view',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('customer')->__('Page View'),
            'width' => '50px',
            'index' => 'page_view_count',
    ));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Comment: I've got this error:  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'o.customer_id' in 'group statement'. I'm not sure why :(