# Display number of orders per customer in admin order view

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, order-grid

I'm trying to display number of orders made per customer in admin order grid, using the following join and select I could get the number or orders.

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.increment_id=sales_flat_order.increment_id','sales_flat_ordercustomer_email');
 $readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getConnection('core_read');
     $select = $readAdapter->select()
        ->from('sales_flat_order') 
        ->columns(array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')))
        ->group('sales_flat_order.customer_email');
                
                $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(  array('orders_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$select.')')),  'sales_flat_order.customer_email = orders_count.customer_email',  array('orders_count.orders_count')); 
        $collection->addFilterToMap('orders_count', 'orders_count.orders_count');
```

this is the result >>

```
increment_id  count_orders  email  
1000001       3             customer@customer.com  
1000008       3             customer@customer.com 
1000015       3             customer@customer.com
```

how could I get sum of orders at time of every order, not sum of all orders

```
increment_id  count_orders  email 
1000001       1             customer@customer.com 
1000008       2             customer@customer.com 
1000015       3             customer@customer.com
```

Comment: Hope this might help [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73017/how-to-join-a-calculated-column-from-a-table-to-collection)

Comment: @Anass HI: did you try this one ?https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177185/get-number-of-orders-per-customer